# Best way to create relational database model for different Customer modals in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

In my Laravel project i have 3 kind of types, `Vehicle Owner, Driver and Customer models`.

When I'm adding credits and debts for all kind. **It's working but I'm not happy** with solution

**Because:**

1. There are several common fields repeates.
2. When user will add credit/invoice which joins with 3 tables.
3. Financial table seems more complex

**Finance**

```
  userType       | userID       | amouth       
  ------         |  ------      |----------- 
  VehicleOwner   |  5           | -500
  Driver         |  5           |  200
  Customer       |  5           |  200
```

Maybe there is a solution could be relate all 3 tables with one  table:

In my case i have many related info between these `type` and would like to use in common instead of joining the data in each table.

1.Driver   (extend driving license info)
2.Customer (extend corporate info)
3.Vehicle Owner (extend driver info)

I'm new in Laravel and looking for best practice? I'm waiting for only laravel code practices.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `user_type` field (tinyint (1)) in `users` table.
All kind of users will be in this table.
Customer will have user type of 1, drivers 2 and vehicle owners 3 etc.

Comment: It's always a good practice.

Check **Dynamics Scopes** from Laravel docs.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes

Answer (score -1):

You can store `amount` in `User model` and add field `user_id` in `Driver`, `Customer` and `Vihacle owner` models.